# builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'seek'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, document, photo, opencv

I am trying to write a program that reads in a folder of photos, analyses their heights and widths, and resizes them accordingly, then sends them to a word document. I keep getting this error and I am unsure what is causing it:

```
from docx import Document
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import glob 
import os 
import numpy
document = Document()

img_dir = "C:/Users/27832/Desktop/Report Images"
data_path = os.path.join(img_dir,'*g') 
files = glob.glob(data_path) 
photos = [] 
for pic in files: 
    imagg = cv2.imread(pic) 
    photos.append(imagg) 

for i in range(0, len(photos)):   
    
    if 0.85*(photos[i].shape[0]) < (photos[i].shape[1]) < 1.15*(photos[i].shape[0]):
        resized_image = photos[i].resize((314, 314))
        document.add_picture(resized_image)
        
    elif (photos[i].shape[1]) >= 0.85*(photos[i].shape[0]):
        resized_image = photos[i].resize((257, 382))
        document.add_picture(resized_image)
  
    elif (photos[i].shape[1]) <= 1.15*(photos[i].shape[0]):
        resized_image = photos[i].resize((401, 325))
        document.add_picture(resized_image)  

        
document.save("C:/Users/27832/Desktop/Word Macro Program/Report.docx")
```

Comment: have you checked `pic` variable values?

Comment: Post the full traceback so we can see what line is causing the error.

Comment: I just edited the code slightly and managed to get rid of the error message. A document is created and saved under the correct folder, however, the document is empty and none of the photos seem to be making it through the entire program, where could they be getting lost?